# SQL Server speed up query

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, stored-procedures

I'm running a stored procedure with multiple joins with one table that contains over 600,000 records. The problem is the procedure is very slow and can take minutes to execute. We have indexed the relevant tables columns and still no luck.

What can we do to help improve performance? The query is posted below.

Thanks

```
with CTE
as
(
select * from 
(
    select distinct c.ContactId, c.FirstName, c.LastName, 
    (select top 1 ce.Email from dbo.ContactEmails as ce where ce.ContactId =  c.ContactId and ce.IsPrimary = 1) as Email, 
    comp.CompanyName, j.JobName, c.MobileNumber, c.OfficeNumber, cse.DateSent, MAX(cse.DateSent) over(partition by ce.email) as maxdate 

    from dbo.ContactSentEmails as cse

    join dbo.ContactEmails as ce on cse.ContactId = ce.ContactId
    join dbo.Contacts as c on ce.ContactId = c.ContactId
    left join dbo.Jobs as j on c.JobId = j.JobId
    left join dbo.Companies as comp on c.CompanyId = comp.CompanyId

    join dbo.StaffProjects as sp on cse.StaffProjectId = sp.StaffProjectId
    join dbo.Staff as s on sp.StaffId = s.StaffId
    join dbo.Projects as p on sp.ProjectId = p.ProjectId

    where (@ContactSourceId = -1 or c.ContactSourceId = @ContactSourceId)
    and (@FirstName = '' OR c.FirstName LIKE '%' + @FirstName + '%')
    and (@LastName = '' OR c.LastName LIKE '%' + @LastName + '%')
    and (@EmailAddress = '' OR ce.Email LIKE '%' + @EmailAddress + '%')
    and (@StaffId = -1 or sp.StaffId = @StaffId)
    and (@ProjectId = -1 or sp.ProjectId = @ProjectId)
    and (@OfficeId = -1 or p.OfficeId = @OfficeId)
    and cse.DateSent between CONVERT(datetime, @startDate) and CONVERT(datetime, @endDate)

    group by c.ContactId, c.FirstName, c.LastName, Email,comp.CompanyName, j.JobName, c.MobileNumber, c.OfficeNumber, cse.DateSent
) as tbContacts
)

select ContactId, FirstName, LastName, Email, CompanyName, JobName, MobileNumber, OfficeNumber from CTE where cte.DateSent = CTE.maxdate order by CTE.Email
```

Comment: The LIKEs with leading wild cards are probably what's hurting you here. No amount of indexing will improve their performance.

Comment: You also have (inner) joins following left (outer) joins. Those left joins will become inner joins based on the table ordering. It looks like they should be able to be moved after all the inner joins without breaking your query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many defects!

Defect 1: No plan can be chosen without looking at supplied values.

```
(@ContactSourceId = -1 or c.ContactSourceId = @ContactSourceId)
```

If @ContactSourceId is -1 you have one query execution plan.  If ContactSourceId is not -1, you have another query execution plan.  If you want the correct execution plan to be chosen, you'll need to provide a query that knows what it is supposed to be filter without looking at the values of the variables.

Since you've used this criteria construct 7 times, there are 2^7 potential plans and your odds of getting the right one is 1/2^7 = 1/128 < 1%

You need to break this query text into 128 different queries - the query optimizer will only do this for you badly.

---

Defect 2: Failure to use SARGable search criteria

One of those 128 queries works like this: Suppose that @FirstName was supplied and the other variables aren't.  In this case, @FirstName is the primary criteria to access the Contacts table.

```
c.FirstName LIKE '%' + @FirstName + '%'
```

If you wrote a query with just this criteria on the Contacts table - there would be no index you can add to the Contacts table that would be used.  You are doomed to table scan.  Learn about SARGable search criteria.

---

Defect 3:  Operations on each row, yields same result for each row.

```
cse.DateSent between CONVERT(datetime, @startDate) and CONVERT(datetime, @endDate)
```

Why are you converting a variable to DateTime on each row?  Do those convert before running the query.

---

Defect 4: 90% of the time Distinct is a crutch

```
distinct
top 1
group by
```

So many "give me just one" operators in a query means the query author was just trying stuff and seeing what sticks.  Simplify to the actual intent.  My guess is the distinct is not needed.  If you add distinct when you don't need it - you still pay for it!

Comment: +1. The wildcards are slow, but the DISTINCT sticks out to me like a sore thumb. A correlated subquery to get the `MAX(DateSent)` will probably work better here instead of the DISTINCT on a potentially massive table.

Comment: Good point about the number of query plans, but I wouldn't exactly describe that a 'defect'. But your point about breaking-this-up into separate queries can be a good pattern to use to improve performance (though of course it makes maintenance potentially more expensive). This is one of the benefits of using dynamic SQL or generating SQL dynamically.

Answer (score 2):

As @Joe wrote in a comment to your question, the `LIKE` operators are expensive, particularly because you're prepending the wildcard to the beginning of each search string. The numerous `OR` operators are also a likely cause of the poor query performance.

See the classic article [Dynamic Search Conditions in T-SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2005.html) by Erland Sommarskog for a great introduction to writing better performing 'search' queries.

[Also, what's with the `SELECT TOP 1` and the `group by ...` with nearly every column in the `SELECT` clause?]

Comment: Im guessing the group by is because he got the column not contained in a group by error and so just added everything to the group by

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i will take a look at that article now. The select top is because there can be more than one email address that is set to primary. I have removed the group clause as its not needed. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As both @Joe and @Kenny say, the `LIKE` operators are probably the biggest cause of your problems. Fixing this will probably lead to the biggest performance improvement. Investigate [full text search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx) and see if it's right for your needs.

However, I would also refactor the way you are selecting the email as a sub-select in the select clause. This is typically a very expensive way to perform a query in SQL Server. Can a contact have more than one email address where `IsPrimary = 1`? If not, then simply join on the table in the main `FROM`. If they can have more than one, consider writing a view (possibly an indexed view) to return the top email address by contact. Then you can join on that.

Comment: yes there can be more than one email where Primary = 1. I will look at doing what you suggested by returning a contact and join on that. Thanks for the post